# Change TimeSpanAxis label color OXYPLOT?

Tags: xamarin.forms, oxyplot

I am able to do formatting except choosing the right color for my label font. Does any one know how to change the color of any axis's label using OxyPlot in Xamarin.Forms ?

Comment: Never mind, found it. 
TextColor = OxyColors.White,

Comment: TextColor is available in PlotElement.

Comment: Feel free to write answer

Answer (score 1):

OP found the answer by himself: The color may be set by assigning a `OxyColor` to the property `TextColor` of any `PlotElement`.

(Just answering to get this question out of "unanswered")